# How to better structure the functions in this script so that it will continue looping without a crash?

Tags: ios, swift

My program is to update the time each second, and using Core Graphics the hours, minutes and seconds will be drawn out using shapes in a `UIView` I created in the storyboard. When I have this script set up in xcode, the `@IBDesignable` aspect updates the appropriate hour time in my storyboard. Below is the `UIView` subclass associated with the `UIView` in the storyboard.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable

class clock: UIView {
    func updateTime() -> (hour:Int, minute:Int, second:Int) {

        var date:NSDate = NSDate()
        var calendar:NSCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        var components:NSDateComponents = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitSecond, fromDate: date)

        var hour = components.hour
        var minute = components.minute
        var second = components.second
        setNeedsDisplay()
        return (hour, minute, second)


        }

    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector: "updateTime", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {





    var hour = updateTime(hour)


        switch hour {

        case 0:

            ClockStyleKit.drawCanvas0()

        case 01, 13:
            ClockStyleKit.drawCanvas0()
            ClockStyleKit.drawCanvas01()

        case 02, 14:
            ClockStyleKit.drawCanvas0()
            ClockStyleKit.drawCanvas01()
            ClockStyleKit.drawCanvas02()
     }
 }
```

When it crashes, the culprit is the line:

```
var hour = updateTime()
```

It throws an error that says

> Variable used within its own initial value.

Any ideas? How can I better structure this to continue updating my time?

Comment: Your probably should move the update time function out of the drawRect function

Comment: I wonder how you were even able to call that method updateTime from outside of it's scope. If you look at it, it is defined inside drawRect and you have been calling from outside the method. Did it even give any warning or compiler error ?

Comment: Please tidy up your code - it makes no sense, and would never compile, so it's clearly not the code for the program that's crashing (specifically, you declare `var timer` and `var hour` twice in the same scope). Note also that you should not call `setNeedsDisplay()` inside `drawRect()` since the effect of `setNeedsDisplay()` is to queue a call to `drawRect()`. And please tidy up the indentation to make the code more readable...

Comment: Sorry about the layout, I miscalculated the formatting in the field. The timer being there twice was fixed, it was a copy paste error and not part of the code. This code has only that one compile error when I return the 3 variables in updateTime () and call it with updateTime (hour). Removing the 3 returned items from updateTime and just returning one variable at a time (e.g. hour) translates into the switch statement properly.